# What would be the simplest way to move VPS server?

Tags: 16.04, vps

My hosting provider doesn't allow to make a backup. I need to move Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to another VPS. What would be the way to do that? Could not find any reliable information on this.

I think that it's probably possible to mount partition over network located on another VPS and `dd` there. But may be there is somewhat else?

Target VPS can be setup from `.iso`.

If upgrade to 18.04 LTS makes things easy I can do this.

Comment: Depends upon what you created, and what you are comfortable with, neither of which we know. My own system likely wouldn't work for you, because I have different services, a different structure, and different skills than you.

Comment: Just suggest a solution (in a couple of words) and it will be clear whether it's suitable for me.

Comment: @user535733 Your comment in this form is absolutely useless. Sounds like: I have an idea, but won't tell you...